# query to show foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table equipment,

this is a data when i select all in table equipment.

```
select * from equipment
```

[image]

in this table equipment have field radio1,radio2,radio3

the value is ID from table radio, here is the tabel radio

```
select * from radio
```

[image]

the question is how to join radio and equipment, and i need the **radio1,radio2,radio3 value is a protocol from table radio**

so the value is

```
radio1     ||     radio2    ||    radio3    ||
UDP        || Serial Number ||              ||
```

Comment: You need to normalize the table.

Comment: How many values can there be in the `radio` table?

Comment: how to normalize table? @FreshPrinceOfSO .

Comment: radio n values @ErikE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your table design is poor you should normalize your table. but if you need like you told. the below will be unefficeint method but check to see if it works.

```
select (select protocal from radio where id=equipemnt.radio1 ) as radio1,
(select protocal from radio where id=equipemnt.radio2 ) as radio2,
(select protocal from radio where id=equipemnt.radio3 ) as radio3
from equipment
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table is violating the rules of database normalization. Putting the values into three separate columns is not the best design. Instead, you should have an `EquipmentRadio` table with columns `EquipmentID, RadioID` having a foreign key relationship to both the `Equipment` and `Radio` tables. You could do that like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EquipmentRadio (
   EquipmentID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_EquipmentRadio_EquipmentID
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Equipment(ID),
   RadioID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_EquipmentRadio_RadioID
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Radio(ID),
   CONSTRAINT PK_EquipmentRadio PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EquipmentID, RadioID)
);

INSERT dbo.EquipmentRadio
SELECT
   E.ID
FROM
   dbo.Equipment E
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (E.Radio1),
      (E.Radio2),
      (E.Radio3)
   ) R (RadioID)
WHERE
   R.RadioID IS NOT NULL -- or `> 0` if appropriate
;

ALTER TABLE dbo.EquipmentRadio DROP COLUMN Radio1;
ALTER TABLE dbo.EquipmentRadio DROP COLUMN Radio2;
ALTER TABLE dbo.EquipmentRadio DROP COLUMN Radio3;
```

Of course, don't do this, especially the dropping columns part, unless you are sure it is all correct. To use this design you'll have to modify your front-end client forms and code appropriately.

Your table will look like this:

```
EquipmentID  RadioID
-----------  -------
     1         1
     1         2
-- (notice there's no third row, but you could have 3 or even more)
```

In the meantime, if you *are* going to just use the three columns that you have, there is a better than using three separate subqueries.

```
SELECT
   E.ID,
   R.* -- should name the columns explicitly, though
FROM
   dbo.Equipment E
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT
         P.*
      FROM
         (
            SELECT U.Radio, R.Protocol
            FROM
               (VALUES
                  ('Radio1', E.Radio1),
                  ('Radio2', E.Radio2),
                  ('Radio3', E.Radio3)
               ) U (Radio, RadioID)
               INNER JOIN dbo.Radio R
                  ON U.RadioID = R.ID
            WHERE
               U.RadioID IS NOT NULL -- or `> 0` if appropriate
         ) X
      PIVOT (Max(X.Protocol) FOR X.Radio IN (Radio1, Radio2, Radio3)) P
   ) R
;
```

What this does is temporarily unpivot the 3 values into 3 rows (like a normalized database would have), then join them in a single join to `Radio`, then finally pivot them back to 3 columns. That's a lot of clunkiness to go through to accommodate a denormalized design.

[See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62428/1)

Note: in my demo I used `NULL` instead of `0` for `Radio3` because that is the only way to have a proper foreign key relationship with the `Radio` table. But the "right" way is to move the radio columns into a new table as I showed you above.

Comment: how to add LEFT JOIN in your query?

Comment: Try it now? I changed `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: what the mean of table `EquipmentID`  `RadioID`? . and then when i use left join the sql error `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: Alex, I can't really give you much more detail. Please read up on "many-to-many" relationships in database design. I don't know why you're getting that error--if you could show me the query you're using it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `radio` once for each `radio...` field in `equipment`, using aliases to distinguish between the `radio` tables:

```
SELECT equipment.*, Radio1.protocol, Radio2.protocol, Radio3.protocol 
FROM equipment INNER JOIN radio as Radio1 ON Radio1.id=equipment.radio1 INNER JOIN radio as Radio2 ON Radio2.id=equipment.radio2 INNER JOIN radio as Radio3 ON Radio3.id=equipment.radio3
```